# Unable to communicate with Watson

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, personality-insights

I'm using the Watson Personality Insights API to return personality insights based on a user's tweets. It has been working fine for the past few weeks, then today it became quite slow and eventually stopped working and gave me this error message.

Is this an issue with Watson / Bluemix / an issue with my code?

> Watson Error
>
> ---
>
> An Internal Server Error has occured - /personality-insights/api/v2/profile?include_raw=true
>
> Unable to access server
>
> Gateway Error Code : ERCD50-LDAP-DN-SRCH-ERR
>
> Unable to communicate with Watson.
>
> Request URL : /personality-insights/api/v2/profile?include_raw=true
>
> Error Id :  gateway-dp02-436619140
>
> Date-Time : 2016-04-21T14:20:29-05:00
>
> ' } url: /api/profile/twitter

The error code doesn't return any search results on google.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We been using this service for over a year now. This is the first time we are seeing this particular exception. I'm certain that watson services are down.

Comment: If you are still seeing this error, please add a comment. Issues with the Watson services were resolved on Apr 21, 2016 at 22:07 UTC according to the Bluemix Status Page: https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, getting the exact same error for Watson Natural language processing, looks like it's an LDAP issue, seems like all the watson services are down right now.